# Query postgres jsonb by value regardless of keys

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I want to get all records where any *value* in jsonb field contains a text regardless of key.

For example: field contains json `{k1: 'hello', k2: 'world'}`. I want to get this record by the text 'hello'. I don't care about keys or any json structure, only values.

One dirty hack is to cast the field to varchar `where jsonb_field::varchar like ...`, but this is ugly and it will match keys and {} as well.

Another dirty hack looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable AS m1 WHERE (
  SELECT string_agg(value, '') FROM jsonb_each_text( (SELECT name FROM mytable AS m2 WHERE m1.id= m2.id)::jsonb ) 
) LIKE '%whatever%';
```

but it's ugly too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple JSONs you can use more appropriate query like

```
select * 
from mytable t 
where exists (
  select 1 
  from jsonb_each_text(t.jsonbfield) j 
  where j.value = 'hello');
```

It works fine for JSONs like in your example but not helps for more complex JSONs  like `{"a":"hello","b":1,"c":{"c":"world"}}`

I can propose to create the stored function like

```
create or replace function jsonb_enum_values(in jsonb) returns setof varchar as $$
begin
  case jsonb_typeof($1)
    when 'object' then
      return query select jsonb_enum_values(j.value) from jsonb_each($1) j;
    when 'array' then
      return query select jsonb_enum_values(a) from jsonb_array_elements($1) as a;
    else
      return next $1::varchar;
  end case;
end
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

to list all values including recursive objects (It is up to you what to do with arrays).

Here is usage example:

```
with t(x) as (
  values
    ('{"a":"hello","b":"world","c":1,"d":{"e":"win","f":"amp"}}'::jsonb),
    ('{"a":"foo","b":"world","c":2}'),
    ('{"a":[{"b":"win"},{"c":"amp"},"hello"]}'),
    ('[{"a":"win"}]'),
    ('["win","amp"]'))
select * 
from t 
where exists (
  select *
  from jsonb_enum_values(t.x) j(x) 
  where j.x = '"win"');
```

Note that doublequotes around the string value.

Comment: If my json contains an array value, it's failing.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy Thanks for attention. Function and example updated.

Comment: I fell like your stored proc will work for my problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252423/searching-for-a-particular-value-in-a-jsonb-datatype-prostgresql ) . I am not sure if this is the most optimised way, any suggestion for my problem .

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy The most optimized way is to use true relational model instead of JSON columns. In few words: if you planning to search for data by content of JSON column - do not use JSON :) Probably that's why you are still have not an answer to your another question. You are using annoying but very popular [anti-pattern](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/)