# Searching for a particular value in a jsonb datatype prostgresql

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql, jsonb

We are storing dynamic json data to a postgresql `jsonb` datatype field. Most of the json keys are dynamic and nested.

Now I need to search one particular value inside this json data field. This value may be present with any key name.

`row1` = { "header": { "piecesids" : [100,200,300] }, "footer" : {"pieceids" : [500,300]} }

`row2` = { "header_right": { "piecesids" : [500,300,400] }, "footer_left" : {"pieceids" : [300,200]} }

`row3` = { "body_right": { "piecesids" : [500,300,600] }, "body_left" : {"pieceids" : [300]} }

I need all the rows where `pieceid` 200 is present that means I want `row1 & row2` to be returned.

I have gone through several blogs, but all mentions how we can search by key but not by value.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't - you'll need to recursively "unnest" it for check, or just try regular expressions on casted to text value

Comment: @VaoTsun : Any suggestion what should be the right way to implement it? I fell like it might hit performance issue if we search by regular expression on a casted text value.

Comment: yes - it definitely will be slow. but it will be so anyway - you want to parse it. no indexes, even no logical way to have any path optimization - right?