# Filter json values regardless of keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table called `diary` which includes columns listed below:

```
| id | user_id | custom_foods       |
|----|---------|--------------------|
| 1  | 1       | {"56": 2, "42": 0} |
| 2  | 1       | {"19861": 1}       |
| 3  | 2       | {}                 |
| 4  | 3       | {"331": 0}         |
```

I would like to count how many diaries having `custom_foods` value(s) larger than 0 each user have. I don't care about the keys, since the keys can be any number in string.

The desired output is:

```
| user_id | count   |
|---------|---------|
| 1       | 2       |
| 2       | 0       |
| 3       | 0       |
```

I started with:

```
select *
from diary as d
join json_each_text(d.custom_foods) as e
on d.custom_foods != '{}'
where e.value > 0
```

I don't even know whether the syntax is correct. Now I am getting the error:

> ERROR:  function json_each_text(text) does not exist
> LINE 3: join json_each_text(d.custom_foods) as e
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

My using version is: psql (10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg14.04+1), server 9.4.19). According to [PostgreSQL 9.4.19 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), that function should exist. I am so confused that I don't know how to proceed now.

Threads that I referred to:

- [Postgres and jsonb - search value at any key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739601/postgres-and-jsonb-search-value-at-any-key)
- [Query postgres jsonb by value regardless of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250331/query-postgres-jsonb-by-value-regardless-of-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `custom_foods` column is defined as text, so you should cast it to json before applying  `json_each_text`. As `json_each_text` by default does not consider empty jsons, you may get the count as 0 for empty jsons from a separate CTE and do a `UNION ALL`

```
WITH empty AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
                    0 AS COUNT
   FROM diary
   WHERE custom_foods = '{}' )
SELECT user_id,
       count(CASE
                 WHEN VALUE::int > 0 THEN 1
             END)
FROM diary d,
     json_each_text(d.custom_foods::JSON)
GROUP BY user_id
 UNION ALL
   SELECT *
FROM empty
ORDER BY user_id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=560b20fd6f5b91ed2673ed45d04fc3fb)